# Can I override SqlCommand functions?

Tags: vb.net

I have code that will be for example

```
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(commandString, databaseString) 
Dim result As Integer

Try
    result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
Catch e as Exception
    'catch exception code
End Try
```

Instead of doing that, can I override the ExecuteScalar function to do some kind of generic exception catching?

Comment: You can write a private method that does some kind of generic exception catching and call it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can create a generic `DoExecuteScalar` helper function that takes a SQL string and connection string:

```
Public Function DoExecuteScalar(commandString as String, databaseString as String) as Object
    Dim cmd as New SqlClient.SqlCommand(commandString, databaseString)
    Dim result as Integer
    Try
        result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    Catch e As Exception
        Return 0
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot override methods because you cannot inherit from it since [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) is [`sealed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx).

What's wrong with catching (or throwing) exceptions where you're using the `SqlCommand`?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use composition:

```
Public Class SqlCommandManager
Private _sqlCommand As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
Public Sub New(command As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)

    If command Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("command")
    End If

    _sqlCommand = command
End Sub
Private ReadOnly Property Command As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Get
        Return _sqlCommand
    End Get
End Property
Public Function ExecuteScalar() As Object
    Dim result As Object

    Try
        result = Command.ExecuteScalar()
    Catch e As Exception
        'catch exception code
    End Try

    Return result
End Function
End Class
```

Not saying this is the best alternative, just that it is one ....